# how to create date picker in asp content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code now how to add date picker for select date month and year
when user click on input then calender is came on the input for select date

Date

Comment: Witch version of .net are you using?

Comment: visual studio 2019

Comment: The .Net version is more about right-click project -> properties, namely the "Target Framework" property

Comment: Actually the question has already been answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469280/asp-net-datetime-picker

Answer (score 0):

Reference Bootstrap bootstrap-material-datetimepicker to your Project

and You Should Create html Input Element And using Tag-Helper connected to DataTime To Property

then add datepicker Attribute to the element

```
<input type="text" asp-for="StartDate" class="form-control" value="" datepicker >
```

Then add the following function to your project and call the InitDateTimePicker function

```
function InitDateTimePicker() {
var dateTimePicker = window.$("[datetimepicker]");
if (dateTimePicker.length > 0) {
    window.$('<link/>',
        {
            rel: 'stylesheet',
            type: 'text/css',
            href: '/' +
                direction +
                '/plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css'
        }).appendTo('head');
    window.$.getScript("/" + direction + "/plugins/momentjs/moment.js",
        function (script, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            window.$.getScript(
                "/" +
                direction +
                "/plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js",
                function (script, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    window.$(dateTimePicker).each(function (index, value) {
                        window.$(value).bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
                            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
                            clearButton: true,
                            weekStart: 1
                        });
                    });
                });
        });
}

var datePicker = window.$("[datepicker]");
if (datePicker.length > 0) {
    window.$('<link/>',
        {
            rel: 'stylesheet',
            type: 'text/css',
            href: '/' +
                direction +
                '/plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css'
        }).appendTo('head');
    window.$.getScript("/" + direction + "/plugins/momentjs/moment.js",
        function (script, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            window.$.getScript(
                "/" +
                direction +
                "/plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js",
                function (script, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    window.$(datePicker).each(function (index, value) {
                        window.$(value).bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
                            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                            clearButton: true,
                            weekStart: 1,
                            time: false
                        });
                    });
                });
        });
}

var timePicker = window.$("[timePicker]");
if (timePicker.length > 0) {
    window.$('<link/>',
        {
            rel: 'stylesheet',
            type: 'text/css',
            href: '/' +
                direction +
                '/plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css'
        }).appendTo('head');
    window.$.getScript("/" + direction + "/plugins/momentjs/moment.js",
        function (script, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            window.$.getScript(
                "/" + direction + "/plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js",
                function (script, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    window.$(timePicker).each(function (index, value) {
                        window.$(value).bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
                            format: 'HH:mm',
                            clearButton: true,
                            date: false
                        });
                    });
                });
        });
}
```

}

Good luck